# How can I figure out the installed ruby version?

Tags: ruby, shell

I need to test for the correct Ruby version before running the script. In project we have file .ruby_version that has number of required version. For example .ruby_version file has:

```
2.5.5
```

I could get current user version of Ruby in user using `ruby --version`, but this command return more information that i needed. For example:

```
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

So my check doesn't work:

```sh
required_ruby=$(cat .ruby-version)
current_ruby=`ruby --version`
if [ "$required_ruby" != "$current_ruby" ]; then
        echo "This project uses Ruby version $required_ruby, try to checkout or install it"
fi
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two special constants `RUBY_VERSION` and `RUBY_PATCH_LEVEL` available in the Ruby interpreter, so you can call the `ruby` command and let it give your desired information.

```sh
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'
2.5.5
```